# Mocking Hibernate Session

Tags: java, hibernate, session, mockito, powermock

I was trying to mock hibernate session. This is the code snippet I tried:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    campaignModel = DraftTestHelper.buildDraftModel();
    if(sessionFactory != null) {
        System.out.println("Session Factory not null");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Session Factory is null");
    session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    if(session != null) {
        System.out.print("Not null");
    }
    else 
        System.out.println("Null");

}
```

Mock Code:

```
@Mock
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@InjectMocks
DraftCampaignModelBuilder draftBuilder;  

private DraftCampaignModel campaignModel;
private Session session;
```

According to console, session factory is not null. But hibernate session is null. Can anyone please help on this?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide your mock code as well.

Comment: Thanks. I added. Please have a look

Comment: So you are no mocking `getCurrentSession()` method. I think you need to mock this method to return something.

Comment: You should mock what is your code, not 3rd party code.

Comment: Peter can you explain more? Then how should we doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to write this in your `@Before` method:

```
when(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(hibernateSession);
```

e.g.

```
@Mock
private HibernateSession hibernateSession;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    when(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(hibernateSession);

    campaignModel = DraftTestHelper.buildDraftModel();
    if(sessionFactory == null) {
        System.out.println("Session Factory is null");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Session Factory is not null");
        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        if(session != null) {
            System.out.print("Session is not null");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Session is null");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah.. a more simpler approach will be just to @Mock  at class level. Thanks for help!!!!! Will accept the answer in few minutes.